# TeamCity and Mercurial via SSH on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mercurial, ssh, teamcity

I am struggling to get our Ubuntu TeamCity server to checkout repos via SSH. Basically my question is, where would I specify the private-key password?

When running a shell on the machine hosting teamcity and being logged in as the user under which teamcity runs, I can run `hg clone ssh://hg@localhost/test` to clone repository "test". But I have to type the user's private key password.

My TeamCity project is setup as:

- Pull Changes From: hg clone ssh://hg@localhost/test
- Password: (password for private-key)

Clicking "Test connection" results in

```
Test connection failed in Test :: Test 42. '/usr/bin/hg identify ssh://hg@localhost/test' command failed.
stdout: remote: Permission denied, please try again.
remote: Permission denied, please try again.
remote: Permission denied (publickey,password).

stderr: abort: no suitable response from remote hg!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the key pair is only used for the *TeamCity* server's interaction with the *Mercurial* repository, the simplest and still secure solution, provided you protect the private key file with restrictive enough access permissions (i.e. read-only for the user which the *TeamCity* server runs as), is to remove the passphrase from the private key. A private key with an empty passphrase will no longer prompt for the passphrase and thus won't require user interaction, enabling an automation solution.

Comment: Yep, works! Thanks.
PS: I think this is related:
http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-21495